# Cannot set background of QMainWindow without changing all QWidget elements background?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, qtstylesheets

I haive my main UI defined as a QMainWindow as I have below:

```
class Widget1(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget1, self).__init__(parent)
        variable_file.init()
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        self.w1 = self
        self.w1.setFixedSize(1080, 810)
```

Then I also have QWidgets inside Group boxes in the main window. I want to have the QMainWindow set to white with the group boxes and QWidgets all being one colour. I format the qss before using it.

In the qss, I have tried:

```
QMainWindow {
    background-color :{{background}};
}
```

and in the qss the group box and qwidget are styled using:

```
 {
    background-color :{{widget_and_group}};
    font: 14px "Poppins";
    color : white ; 
}
```

This causes all the background to be {widget_and_group} colour.

I have also tried:

```
QWidget {
    background-color :{{background}};
    font: 14px "Poppins";
    color : white ; 
}

QStackedWidget {
    background-color :{{widget_and_group}};
    font: 14px "Poppins";
    color : white ; 
}
```

This partially works my background has the right colour but I have a QStackedWidget which holds QWidgets which is the background colour as well so it does not work for me.

The final thing I have tried is to set the QWidget #bk(name of my background/QMainWindow) specifically like this:

```
QWidget {
    background-color :{{widget_and_group}};
    font: 14px "Poppins";
    color : white ; 
}

QWidget #bk{
    background-color :{{background}};
    font: 14px "Poppins";
    color : white ; 
}
```

But this leads to every QWidget being the same colour and #bk is not the background colour.

I need the QMainWindow to be one colour and QWidgets to be a separate colour.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What "QWidgets"? Please provide a valid and complete [mre] including valid QSS and how you're setting them.

Comment: This is intentional behaviour. QSS is practically CSS 2.x without some features.

Answer (score 0):

Add setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground); into your def __init function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).